# str.split gives different results for direct and read_csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Could any expert tell me why I get different results when I use str.split with a direct string frame and the same string read from a .csv file using pandas ?

```
    data="0 2017/09/28 19:04:05.897106 72.9605 87 ECU1 AMFM HADT 991 log info verbose 1 991 :: 745 :: T[4]HSU(267) fq 98600, fs -12, hwQ 92, pQ 0, afQ 0, mp 65, ofs -300, adj 123, bw 114, stp 0, hl 5EECB57"
df = pd.DataFrame([data],columns=["Data"])
print df.Data.str.split(' ',13).tolist()
df = pd.read_csv("temp1.csv",names=["Data"],header=None)
print df.head(1)["Data"].str.split(' ', 13).tolist()
```

temp1.csv contains only one line i.e.the same as data.

Outputs:

**for print 1:**

```
[['0', '2017/09/28', '19:04:05.897106', '72.9605', '87', 'ECU1', 'AMFM', 'HADT', '991', 'log', 'info', 'verbose', '1', '991 :: 745 :: T[4]HSU(267) fq 98600, fs -12, hwQ 92, pQ 0, afQ 0, mp 65, ofs -300, adj 123, bw 114, stp 0, hl 5EECB57']]
```

**for print 2:**

```
[['', 'hl', '5EECB57']]
```

I want the outputs to be the same as print 1.

Comment: Can you add `df.head(5)` after `df = pd.read_csv(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its the problem with separator in `pd.read_csv`. By default `sep` is ',' so its splitting based on `,` and converting it into dataframe. So to ignore that use double space or any different separator thats not in the csv.

For eg use

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp1.csv",names=["Data"],header=None,sep='\s\s+')
```

Comment: +1 Thanks it worked with  a little modification. df = pd.read_csv("temp1.csv",names=["Data"],header=None,sep='\s\s',engine='python'). But still I wonder why the command for single space '\s' throws error.

Comment: Its because there is single space is available most commonly in the csv and pandas try to create new columns based on that. Since you put only one column it leads to error.

Comment: @ Bharath I would surely vote but I dont have the rights yet. Meanwhile I am struggling now to get the above logic to work for the below data line.'data="13161 2017/09/28 19:04:49.799473 0.0000 1 AOXM 0 control request non-verbose 0 [set_default_log_level] 04 00 00 00 00". ' three spaces after AOXM. It fails with raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: Expected 1 fields in line 1, saw 2 – Biswal 23 mins ago

Comment: It need not be space any absent sep pattern is fine like `sep='$xI*S'` or `sep='non occurning pattern'` since you want th entire string.

Comment: Thanks. Solved with df = pd.read_csv(tmp_csv_outfile,names=["Data"],header=None,sep='\s\s+$',engine='python')